# Thumbnails in Finder for larger files

Tags: macos, finder

I have multiple svg files in a single folder and only a few of them have thumbnails - all those less than 10MB have thumbnails and all those larger do not. Is there a size limit for generating thumbnails in finder?  Is there some way of increasing that limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finder will not generate thumbnails for files larger than 10 MB, unless it's a package with a Quick Look preview pre-generated, such as a large Pages document. It doesn't seem to be possible to increase the limit currently. You can provide feedback to Apple here:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html

Comment: What a bother.  Ubuntu has had the ability to increase that limit for quite a few years now...  I'll submit that request to Apple.